# How would you approach unknown states/variables in steady-state or equilibrium?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, taylor-expansion, dynamical-systems

Consider a linear state space system $\dot{x}=Ax+B$, with $x$ being a $n\times 1$ vector of $n$ state variables, and $A$ and $B$ being known matrices with dimensions $n\times n$ and $n\times m$, respectively. For this example, $n=6$.

The controllability matrix of the system is a full rank matrix and thus, the system is controllable.

However, only $3$ out of $n=6$ state variables appear on the right-hand side. In other words, the system is controlled by just half of the state variables. When performing a linearization $\dot{x}=0$, the linearized state vector $\bar x$ is defined, but just values for the three controlling states are found, whilst the other three are undefined. How can I approach these undefined states in order to find their steady-state value?

For example, say $x=[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_6]$, with linearization by Taylor's Series leading to linearized states $\bar x=[\bar x_1,\bar x_2,\dots,\bar x_6]$. Solely $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ appear in the right-hand side of the state space system. Therefore, solely a value for $\bar x_1,\bar x_2$ and $\bar x_3$ can be found. The other three linearized states $\bar x_4,\bar x_5$ and $\bar x_6$ remain undefined, as they are not necessarily zero. The question in this example would then be: how can I define the linearized states $\bar x_4,\bar x_5$ and $\bar x_6$?

Comment: It is determined by your specification. For instance, most physical systems will require that speed be 0 to do linearization about, but allow you to linearize about any position. It is the control specification that determines the remaining undetermined states (e.g. what position you want to regulate to).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you mean with control specification? In my example I'm looking into chemical dynamics, so $x$ would be concentration, whereas $\dot{x}$ would then be concentration over time.

Comment: I see, i thought this was about control theory (you have an input, a system and want to drive the system somewhere) because you mentioned controllability. The control specification is the latter goal: what you want to do with the system state using your input. Anyway, if the equilibrium states are undetermined by $\dot{x} = 0$, _you_ can choose the remaining components based on external factors.

Comment: Yes this is indeed about control theory where a concentration output gives feedback necessary to control the inputs in order to stabilize the system. I don't see how I can approach the remaining components with external factors, but do these actually matter if they are not measured?

Comment: Uh i guess with an affine system no... but it matters when you implement the controller.

Comment: But that is indeed the only way to "choose" the remaining states. You could choose arbitrarily, but that is the primary way to choose.